# Node (Express) middlewares - how to properly tie back to different endpoints

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, endpoint

I'm starting to dab into Express and they have this feature of middleware, which I'm exploring at the moment.

So let's say I have 2 endpoints (`/middlewaredemoa`, `/middlewaredemob`), they both require some different initial treatment. Then they have a common middleware applying to same treatment regardless of the initial endpoint.

Where I'm not sure I'm doing this right is when supplying the response with the GET(). It seems to me that if I have 2 different endpoint, they each need their own `app.get("/middlewaredemoa", ...)`. Is it necessarily so? Let's say I'm just applying some treatment to a variable then I need to return that var in whichever state it ends up in, would I still be best to define 1 get() per endpoint?

```
let response = ""
app.use('/middlewaredemoa', (req, resp, next) => {
    response = "Greetings from: M1a"

    if ( Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) >=4){
        console.log("M1a gets req and passes it on to two")
        next()
    } else {
        throw "ARRRRRRRRRRRRRGGGGHHHHHH!"
    }
})

app.use('/middlewaredemob', (req, resp, next) => {
    response = "Greetings from: M1b"

    if ( Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) >=4){
        console.log("M1b gets req and passes it on to two")
        next()
    } else {
        throw "ARRRRRRRRRRRRRGGGGHHHHHH!"
    }
})

//some common treatment for all the above endpoints
app.use((req, resp, next) => {
    response += " and M2"

    if ( Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) >=4){
        console.log("M2 gets req and passes it on to GET()")
        next()
    } else {
        throw "ARRRRRRRRRRRRRGGGGHHHHHH!"
    }
})

//get - need 1 get per endpoint?
app.get("/middlewaredemoa",(req,resp) => {
    console.log("GET() handler after the middlewares")
    resp.send(response + " and GET() 1")
})
app.get("/middlewaredemob",(req,resp) => {
    console.log("GET() handler after the middlewares")
    resp.send(response + " and GET() 2")
})

/*ERROR HANDLING - could use same pattern as above to chain errors*/

app.use((err, req, resp, next) => {
    console.log("CRASH BOOM UH!:"+err)
    resp.status(500).send("Poop hit the fan HARD")
})
```

Comment: Are you talking about the `array of routes` express feature? https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#path-examples

Comment: Kinda of - I get the point that a single middleware can match multiple paths through, say, regex or just common routing. However I haven't done a whole lot of server-side coding. So my question is really more about the response (GET, POST etc...), not so much about the middleware...

Comment: So, do you want `req.get(['route1', 'route2'], (req, res, next) => {})`?

Comment: So, instead of writing two blocks of `.get()` like you did at the bottom, you can just use one `req.get`.

Comment: That's much nicer way to code I think as it's more concise and easier to read. Propose that as an answer and I'M happy with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express offers a way to use arrays to match multiple routes.

Like this:

```
req.get(['/routea', '/routeb'], (req, res, next) => {
 // do something
 // res.send() if you want to send a response right away
 // next() if you want to go to the next middleware
});
```

`req.get` is just a middleware similar to `req.use` except it only matches `req.method === 'GET'`

EDIT: for bonus questions in the comments.
It's just a middleware. Use the same scaling techniques as you would for a normal middleware.

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the details about scaling. Just trying not to code myself into deadends later on....